# gnuplot: Too many tooltips appearing at once on HTML canvas, causes browser freeze

Tags: gnuplot

I'm using gnuplot to create a scatter plot with potentially quite a few data points (greater than 1,000,000). I use the following command to plot the data and allow tooltips on mouse hover (the terminal is html canvas as these plots are meant to be displayed in a website):

```
plot "$resultsFile" using 2:(stringcolumn(8) eq "chr$chrom"?\$5:1/0):1 with labels hypertext point pt 7 ps var lc rgb "black"
```

The issue I'm having is: when I move my mouse over a dense cluster of datapoints, so many tooltips are displayed as the mouse moves that the browser freezes for a few seconds or even longer in an attempt to display them all. Does anyone know a way to stop this from happening? Perhaps by adding a delay before the tooltip is displayed on mouse over.